# How to have two mapbox raster layers with different opacities?

Tags: mapbox, opacity, mapbox-gl-js

Im using Mapbox GL API, and I run into the issue that if I add 2 tile layers, that the opacity of the second layer in the paint object is ignored. Does anyone have any idea why this is? In the browser both tile layers have opacity 1.

```
let style1 = {
    id: "source1-tile",
    type: "raster",
    source: "source1",
    paint: {
        "raster-opacity": 1.0
    },
}
this.map.addLayer(style1);

let style2 = {
    id: "source2-tile",
    type: "raster",
    source: "source2",
    paint: {
        "raster-opacity": 0.5
    },
}
this.map.addLayer(style2);


// print result
console.log(this.map.getStyle().layers)

// this shows the following:
/* 
[
    {
        id: "source1-tile"
        paint: Object { "raster-opacity": 1 }
        source: "source1"
        type: "raster"
    },
    {
        id: "source2-tile"
        source: "source2"
        type: "raster"
    }
] 
*/
```

Comment: That code looks fine. Please post a link to a codepen or similar showing the problem in action.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to add layers in map.load event. I've made this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ToniBCN/yh3o7jnb/6/) based on mapbox-gl examples. Easily You could add more raster layers with different opacity.

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibHN0aXoiLCJhIjoiY2s5dGtnNTZ2MWVybzNobjEyam0yd2E3MyJ9.6dCvGbS93SKGMbOqZA4Qag';
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
        center: [-87.62, 41.86], 
        zoom: 9 
    });

    map.on('load', () => {
        map.addSource('chicago', {
            'type': 'raster',
            'url': 'mapbox://mapbox.u8yyzaor'
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'chicago',
            'source': 'chicago',
            'type': 'raster'
        });

  map.setPaintProperty(
    'chicago',
    'raster-opacity',
    0.5
  );
```

});